# Checking for Operator precedence?

Tags: c++, operators, token

So i'm making a parser for a project, its asking me to make an if statement that checks if my current token is a left associative operator AND if that token has greater precedence than the top of my stack. I have no idea how to check for the precedence.

The project is eventually going to be a calculator that takes in the input and switches it into reverse polish notation. So the code will not know what operators are to be checked until input is received.

```
while(is<Operator>(infixTokens.at(i)){
  if(is<LAssocOperator>(infixTokens.at(i)) && infixTokens.at(i) >=tkn.top()){
  //exits while loop
  }
}
```

tkn is a stack and infixTokens is a vector.
the >= doesn't seem to be working.
What would be the best way to check which operator held in each element is greater than the other?

Comment: see here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working" is not a valid question. Nobody except you know what "tkn" is, or the definition of all the classes and templates referenced in the tiny code snippet you posted, which offers no clue about the rest of your code.

Comment: I did mention tkn was a stack. the whole code is way too big to put in. all i need to know is how on earth i check which operator has greater precedence than the other when i have no clue what operators will be checked.

Comment: You obviously need to know what all the operators are. Then you need to know their relative precedence. Once you have that information, the rest of the code should be obvious.

Comment: If you don't know what operators will be checked, how do you propose to handle them once you see them? The assignment should specify which operators are required. If not, go back and get a tighter spec. You do not want to finish the job, go to the customer to ask for payment, and be told, "But we also want it to do partial derivatives. No money for you until we have partial derivative support!" The first step to a successful project is a firm and agreed-upon set of requirements.

Comment: you should tell my professor that lol, From my understanding it seems to be  +-/%* ,but i'm not entirely sure if that will change in any future projects that require me to expand on this code. plus even if i did know all the operators im checking for, im still not sure how to check for the precedence as that is not something i have learned yet.

Comment: Then go with what you know is required, but try to design the program in such a way that it will be easy to add in new operators later.

Comment: im trying lol but this is where I got stuck. I understand operator precedence but when it comes to writing code that checks which operator has greater precedence over the other, i'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple simple ways.

The easiest is a list of operators sorted by precedence. If the new operator is before the operator on top of the stack, the new operator has higher precedence. Won't spend much time here because it is fatally flawed. This has problems because many operators have the same precedence (+ and -, for example) and must be performed in the order in which they are found.

Second one is a mapping between operator and it's precedence. For example:

```
struct Operator
{
    std::string op;
    int precedence;
}
```

In this case, you compare `precedence` to see which is greater.

```
if (newoperator.precedence > stack.peek().precedence)
{
    // do something
}
else if (newoperator.precedence < stack.peek().precedence)
{
    // do something else
}
else
{ 
    // do whatever you do when the operators have the same precedence
}
```

And because this is C++ you can

```
struct Operator
{
    std::string op;
    int precedence;
    int prioritycompare(const Operator & other)
    {
        return precedence - other.precedence;
    }
}
```

To make life a bit easier for you.

And then you can go even further and establish a class hierarchy, though at this point in your programming career you probably don't want to go here yet. Take my word for it, it's a lot easier to write.

```
struct Operator
{
    std::string op;
    int precedence;
    ~Operator()
    {
        \\does nothing
    }
    virtual int operate(int A, int B) = 0; // pure virtual function
    int prioritycompare(const Operator & other)
    {
        return precedence - other.precedence;
    }
}

struct plus: public Operator
{  
    int operate(int A, int B)
    {
        return A+B;
    }
}
```

Then if you have a any operator in hand, you can test for precedence and perform the operation

```
result = newoperator.operate(val1, val2);
```

and not care exactly what kind of operator it is because the magic of polymorphism takes care of the book-keeping for you. The program will call the correct function for the correct class.

Comment: This is wrecking havoc with my current class hierarchy. The types refuse to line up at all. Is there no simpler way of doing this? I feel like there is as the "pseudo" code my professor has given me seems to suggest so although doesnt show me how... i feel like im missing something here

Comment: "The easiest is a list of operators sorted by precedence. If the new operator is before the operator on top of the stack, the new operator has higher precedence." what would be the best way to do that?